# Powershell: Search a file, export it to the Event Log - How To

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell, event-viewer

How Do I parse an XML file to a string, so I can take that data, and create an Event Log with that parsed data being in the -Message portion of the command.

example: Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Custom Alert” –EntryType Information –EventID 1 –Message “I want this information from the parsed xml file here.”

Comment: So you want this script to constantly run in the background monitoring for file changes in that folder?

Comment: Ok, so you have two questions, right? One is monitoring a folder for changes (FileSystemWatcher) and the other is reading a node value or node attribute from an XML file? If that is correct, I recommend breaking up this question into two questions.

Comment: Ok.. First question:
How Do I parse an XML file, so I can take that data, and create an Event Log with that parsed data being in the -Message portion of the command.

example:
Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Custom Alert” –EntryType Information –EventID 1  –Message “I want this information from the parsed xml file here.”

Comment: TheMadTechnician:  I am trying NOT to have a "Watcher" setup persay.. I can and have built that script just fine if I do go that route.. its the parsing of the XML and taking that data into the Event Log I want to create as the -Message i am having a harder time with.   

I dont need to save files persay..

Comment: I figured out how to get the contents of an XML file into the  -Message portion of an Event log, the answer is: 

Get-Content "C:\test\*.xml" {Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source CustomAlert -EntryType Information -EventId 999 -Message (Get-Content 'C:\test\*.xml')